# Detect and correct unit errors in longitudinal data

Tags: r

I have a very large longitudinal dataset with weights of thousands of individuals. The unit of weight used (pounds/kg) is entered along with the weight. There are a significant proportion of mistakes in the dataset, where weight is entered in a different unit than the selected. When displaying weight curves over time (converted to kg), unit errors at single time points clearly stand out as these measurements typically deviate by a factor of 2.2 (1 kg = 2.20462 pounds) from the individuals weight curve, as shown in the figure below.

[image: Weight curves with unit errors]

I realize that there is no perfect solution to this problem, and given the size of the dataset, it is not possible to manually inspect or correct individual errors. So I am looking for an efficient algorithm that can detect the most obvious mistakes and correct them.

My current approach is not perfect, but consists of a loop over subjects where:

1. I check if the ratio of max and min weight entries for the subject are greater than 1.5, if so, I go to 2), if not, i move to the next subject
2. If the subject only has 2 observations and the ratio is greater than 3.5, the corrected weights are computed by multiplying the max observation by 1/2.20462 and the min by 2.20462, if the ratio is less than 3.5, the corrected weights are set to NA
3. If a subject has more than 2 observations: Observations are sorted in decreasing order by absolute deviation from the median. Iterating over the sorted observations, it is computed if the standard deviation of the subject's observations decreases by multiplying the weight by 1/2.20462 or 2.20462, if so, the corrected weight is set to the weight multiplied by the associated factor and everything is recomputed based on the corrected weights in the next step

I have two questions:

1. Are there standard approaches for this type of problem that are already implemented in R?
2. Can my algorithm or something close to it be compactly implemented in tidyverse?

Here is an example dataset:

```
weight_dat <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
                                    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
                                    3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
                                    4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), 
                             years_bl = c(0, 1.46, 2.34, 3.06, 5.28, 6.36, 7.01, 
                                          9.37, 10.08, 10.31, 0, 4.45, 4.76, 
                                          7.07, 10.3, 11.33, 0, 1.13, 1.86, 
                                          2.26, 5.67, 7.37, 7.5, 11.94, 12.31, 
                                          0, 0.7, 2.54, 4.26, 4.55, 5.79, 7.93, 
                                          9.89, 11.85, 0, 1.04, 4.01, 5.98, 
                                          8.16, 9.57, 13.68), 
                             weight_kg = c(78.7, 78.8, 75.8, 79.9, 82.8, 77.1, 
                                           81.2, 80.8, 82.9, 85.3, 74.1, 75.7, 
                                           78, 80.3, 90.5, 85, 90.2, 196.5, 
                                           85.7, 79.8, 83, 83, 80, 74.8, 71, 
                                           39.5, 81.5, 80, 79, 79.1, 77.8, 70.7, 
                                           33.3, 65.4, 72.1, 75.6, 79, 67.4, 
                                           69.4, 64.5, 67.3)), 
                        class = 'data.frame')
```

Comment: I would suggest that this question should not have the "tidyverse" tag. To quote the tag description, "ONLY use this tag if your question relates to the installation, integration with your system, or inclusion of the entire tidyverse library. DO NOT USE if your question relates to one or two components of the tidyverse, such as dplyr or ggplot2. Use *those* tags, and tag with `r` as well for a better response." This question does not seem to be about the tidyverse.

Answer (score 1):

You are basically looking for outliers.  There are several ways to do this, but they all depend on how you define what an outlier is, i.e., how far from the rest a given value has to be in order for it to be considered an aberration.

As you already know, an automated method will always be dependent on the magnitude of the error, and how that relates to how the (correctly measured) values vary.  If you are sure that the error introduced is much larger than the expected variation along time, I suggest the two usual options:

#### Using z-scores

z-scores, which indicate how far each value is from the mean, and measure that in standard deviations.  You calculated them by subtracting the mean and dividing the result by the standard deviation.  Since each individual will have its own mean and standard deviation, you'll want to calculate them separately for each ID:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

weight_zs <-
  weight_dat %>%
  mutate_at("id", factor) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(z = (weight_kg - mean(weight_kg)) / sd(weight_kg))
```

A z-score of 2 will then indicate that a given value is 2 standard deviations above that individual's mean.  You then need to find an appropriate threshold for what constitutes an outlier: 1.96 is an usual choice, since the interval between -1.96*SD and 1.96*SD contains 95% the values of a normal-distributed variable (I won't go farther that this, otherwise we'd be getting into [Cross validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) territory).  In the code below I use `abs(z) > 2` to detect outliers on both sides, but if you are absolutely sure that all you errors are positive, you can just use `z > 2`.

```
ggplot(weight_zs, aes(x = years_bl, y = weight_kg, colour = id)) +
geom_line() +
geom_point(aes(size = abs(z) > 2))
```

[image]

In you case, 2 seems to be too high (there are some unexpectedly low values that don't get detected as outliers).  You can test other values, perhaps on a subset of your data, but It'll always be a bit trial-and-error, I'm afraid.

#### Median + IQR

Another usual definition is the one used for instance in `ggplot2`'s boxplots,
which sets the outlier threshold as median +/- 1.5 * interquartile range:

```
weight_out <-
  weight_dat %>%
  mutate_at("id", factor) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(outlier = (weight_kg > (median(weight_kg) + 1.5 * IQR(weight_kg))) |
                   (weight_kg < (median(weight_kg) - 1.5 * IQR(weight_kg))))

weight_out %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = years_bl, y = weight_kg, colour = id)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(aes(size = outlier))
```

[image]

This seems to work a bit better.

#### Other considerations

I believe you can easily adapt the above code if you want to implement your own algorithm.  The `case_when` function might help on the first step.  Also, note that both the methods I showed above and your algorithm assume that the mean (or median) is constant over time.  If, for instance, you are measuring individuals that are expected to grow in weight over time, you are more likely to (automatically) find outliers at the start and at the end of the time series, when the individual is smaller or larger than its mean/median weight, which is calculated using the entire time series.  This could be addressed by something like fitting a regression model for each individual and find the outliers by inspecting its residuals, or Cook's distance.

Comment: Thank you for all your efforts, while I don't think that your answer fully addresses the question, the median + IQR code is helpful! For outlier detection, simply identifying outliers by thresholding will perform much worse than using the information that is available about the expected magnitude of unit errors (should be around a factor 2.2 difference).

Comment: The thing is, as a general rule, I believe you'll always need to consider the variability inherent to your data. A 2.2x difference from any central tendency measure might be a correct reading, if there is great variability within the data. But of course you know your data much better than me, so if you are relatively sure that that is a valid criteria, by all means use it.

Comment: If the errors are isolated events, you can also consider looking for spikes, e.g. calculating differences from the previous or next value (or the average of both, or longer rolling averages e.g. `rollmean` from the `zoo` package). Big leaps might be a good indicator that something's wrong.